# missing "CSV File Import" widget in orange

Tags: orange

I don't have the "CSV File Import" widget. according to various screenshots, it should be the second item (also a right-click and search yields nothing ...).

my system:

- ubuntu 20.04
- orange: 3.30.2
- python 3.7.8

I followed the PIP installation from here https://orangedatamining.com/download/#linux

any ideas or know issues?